# Updating a Table on Entity Framework only works when is debugged step by step

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I trying to update a Relation Table of my users with companies (providers). When i do update (first removing old related relations) and later adding selected.

The problem is that if not are debugged only add records but if debug step by step works Ok. Something is wierd but i dont know what.

this is the code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "UsuarioId,Username,Password,Name,LastName,Email,IsActive, Matricula, Cuit,CP, AddressName,AddressNumber,Telefono1, Telefono2,Movil,destiny")] AppUsers_WrapperPOST applicationUser) 
{    
    var companies = Request.Form["companies"];    

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companies)) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Companies", "One or more company is required");
        return View();
    } 

    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        var companiesId = companies.Split(new char[] {','})
            .Select(n = > Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
        var selectedCompanies = db.Companies.Where(
            x = > companiesId.Contains(x.Id) && x.IsActive);
        var usrList = db.AplicationUsers.Where(
            x = > x.UserId == applicationUser.UserId).ToList();
        AppUser usr = new AppUser();

        if (usrList.Any()) 
        {
            usr = usrList.FirstOrDefault();
            var companiesToAdd = selectedCompanies;
            applicationUser.Companies = companiesToAdd;
            CopyClass.CopyObject(applicationUser, ref usr);
            db.Entry(usr).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(applicationUser);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `db.SaveChanges();` instead of `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: I have also tried     db.SaveChanges()     and I was the same result. :(